# query is returning list of anonymous types, want list of values instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I am performing a custom query using LINQ that returns me a list of anonymous types based on my statement:

```
            var currUnitFaster = (from unit in pacificRepo.Units
                                 join loc in pacificRepo.GeoLocations on new { unit.geo_location.Latitude, unit.geo_location.Longitude } equals new { loc.geo_location.Latitude, loc.geo_location.Longitude }
                                 join st in pacificRepo.UnitStatuses on unit.c_number equals st.c_number
                                 select new { 
                                    index = "0", 
                                    unit.c_number, 
                                    unit.serial_number, 
                                    unused = "0", 
                                    unit.ip_address, 
                                    unit.build_version,
                                    status = (st.status == Pacific.Domain.Entities.UnitStatus.Statuses.COMPLETE) ? "<font color=\"green\">" + st.stage + "</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">" + st.stage + "</font>", 
                                    location = (loc==null) ? "Unknown" : loc.city + ", " + loc.state_abbrv,
                                    unit.location_at_address,
                                    latitude = unit.geo_location.Latitude,
                                    longitude = unit.geo_location.Longitude
                                 }).ToList();
```

Therefore, each element returned in the list is an anonymous type:

```
        currUnitFaster[0].ToString() ==> "{ index = 0, c_number = J0000014, serial_number = A2F0JA02, unused = 0, ip_address = 169.254.0.9, build_version = J1, status = <font color=\"green\">Link</font>, location = San Jose, CA, location_at_address = FCC, latitude = 37.390791, longitude = -121.905775 }"
```

Instead of having a list of anonymous types, I would like a list of values.  Such that:

```
currUnitFaster.First()[0] ==> "0"
currUnitFaster.First()[1] ==> "J0000014"
currUnitFaster.First()[2] ==> "A2F0JA02"
...
```

What is the easiest way to do this?  I know that I can simply create a list, and then iterate through each element in `currUnitFaster` and manually add it to that list.  I was wondering if there is some cleaner transformation or casting-based way to do this.

---

**Edit**: I have taken the suggestion of Selman to change `select new` to `select new object[]`.  **However, I now get the following Exception trying to run the query:**

```
Exception: {"Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `select new`   to `select new object[]` and remove the property names.

Edit: it seems EF is complaining about casts.Try this:

```
var currUnitFaster = (from unit in pacificRepo.Units
                      join loc in pacificRepo.GeoLocations on new { unit.geo_location.Latitude, unit.geo_location.Longitude } equals new { loc.geo_location.Latitude, loc.geo_location.Longitude }
                      join st in pacificRepo.UnitStatuses on unit.c_number equals st.c_number
                      select new 
                            { 
                                index = "0", 
                                unit.c_number, 
                                unit.serial_number, 
                                unused = "0", 
                                unit.ip_address, 
                                unit.build_version,
                                status = (st.status == Pacific.Domain.Entities.UnitStatus.Statuses.COMPLETE) ? "<font color=\"green\">" + st.stage + "</font>" : "<font color=\"red\">" + st.stage + "</font>", 
                                location = (loc==null) ? "Unknown" : loc.city + ", " + loc.state_abbrv,
                                unit.location_at_address,
                                latitude = unit.geo_location.Latitude,
                                longitude = unit.geo_location.Longitude
                          })
                        .ToList()
                       .Select(x => new object[] { // write all properties here like x.index, x.c_number });
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip!  I did the following, but now am getting an `Unable to cast the type 'system.Nullable1...to type System.Object` ... does something else need to change also?

Comment: This does not work, throwing the exception I've given in my edited question

Comment: @gnychis see my update, first create a list of anonymous types then perform another projection.Also you can use ToList after second Select  if you want, then you can access your values using indices like: `currUnitFaster[0][0]`, `currUnitFaster[0][1]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that will hold all of your values, such as:

```
public class MyClass {
  public int index { get; set; }
  public int c_number { get; set; }
  public string serial_number { get; set; }
  public int unused get; set; }
  public string ip_address get; set; }
  public string build_version { get; set; }
  public Status statuses { get; set; }
  public int index { get; set; }

  ...etc...
}
```

then do:

```
var currUnitFaster = (from unit in pacificRepo.Units
                                 join loc in pacificRepo.GeoLocations on new { unit.geo_location.Latitude, unit.geo_location.Longitude } equals new { loc.geo_location.Latitude, loc.geo_location.Longitude }
                                 join st in pacificRepo.UnitStatuses on unit.c_number equals st.c_number
                                 select new MyClass { 
                                    index = 0, 
                                    c_number = unit.c_number, 
                                    serial_number = unit.serial_number, 
                                    ...etc...

                                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Based on the exact wording of the question, this should have been selected as an answer. This is exactly what I was going to suggest. For real, who and why downvote? Please explain.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I didn't up vote either.  That is because your suggested solution: 1) requires someone to create a new class just for a single query, and 2) does not actually provide the solution requested?  It seems as though your end result will again be an array of anonymous types

Comment: This is your assumption that it's for a single query, as he didn't specify how often he would use it. Just because a class is created for a single query doesn't make it a bad idea, it actually makes the code cleaner, and easier to understand in the future. This does solve his issue. He was concerned w/ anonymous types. From the question: `What is the easiest way to do this? I know that I can simply create a list, and then iterate through each element in currUnitFaster and manually add it to that list. **I was wondering if there is some cleaner transformation or casting-based way to do this.**`

Comment: To your second point, unless I'm missing something, my method would end up with a var of type List<MyClass> .. how is this an array of anonymous types?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the

```
select new {
```

part. You should define the type you want (and it should fit the data you return), by changing it to something like

```
select new MyExpectedReturnType {
```